# Figure out of if an image is black and white using imagemagick

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a directory of images that I need to seperate into colour vs black and white. This was easy to detect using image magik getImageType. However some images would be considered black and white but have some shades of yellow.

Is there a known way to look at some values and determine its still technically black and white

Image that counts as black and white but comes back as true colour: [image]

Script

```
<?php

$dir = getcwd();
$dirToImages = getcwd().'/imagesToScan/';
$files = scandir($dirToImages);
$badFiles = array('.DS_Store', '.', '..', 'index.php', 'bAndW', 'color');
@mkdir('colour');
@mkdir('bAndW');
echo "\n\n starting script, counting images: \n\n";
echo "image count: ".count($files)."  \n\n ";

foreach($files as $file) {
    /* if the file is shit, its not an image, skip it */
    if (in_array($file, $badFiles)) {
        continue;
    }
    /* directories or bad files don't have an extension, fool proof */
    $exploded = explode('.', $file);
    if (!isset($exploded[1])) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $file;
    /* okay do the work */
    $imagick_type = new Imagick();
    $file_to_grab = $dirToImages.'/'.$file;
    $file_handle_for_viewing_image_file = fopen($file_to_grab, 'a+');
    $imagick_type->readImageFile($file_handle_for_viewing_image_file);
    $image_type = $imagick_type->getImageType();

    switch($image_type)
    {
        case imagick::IMGTYPE_UNDEFINED:
            $image_type_title = "Undefined";
            break;

        case imagick::IMGTYPE_BILEVEL:
            $image_type_title = "Bilevel";
            break;

        case imagick::IMGTYPE_GRAYSCALE:
            $image_type_title = "Grayscale";
            break;

        case imagick::IMGTYPE_GRAYSCALEMATTE:
            $image_type_title = "Grayscale Matte";
            break;

        case imagick::IMGTYPE_PALETTE:
            $image_type_title = "Palette";
            break;

        case imagick::IMGTYPE_PALETTEMATTE:
            $image_type_title = "Palette Matte";
            break;

        case imagick::IMGTYPE_TRUECOLOR:
            $image_type_title = "Truecolor";
            break;

        case imagick::IMGTYPE_TRUECOLORMATTE:
            $image_type_title = "Truecolor Matte";
            break;

        case imagick::IMGTYPE_COLORSEPARATION:
            $image_type_title = "Color Separation";
            break;

        case imagick::IMGTYPE_COLORSEPARATIONMATTE:
            $image_type_title = "Color Separation Matte";
            break;

        case imagick::IMGTYPE_OPTIMIZE:
            $image_type_title = "Optimize";
            break;
    }

    if ($image_type == 2) {
//        copy($dirToImages.'/'.$file, $dir.'/bAndW/'.$file);
    } else {
//        copy($dirToImages.'/'.$file, $dir.'/colour/'.$file);
    }
    echo $file."
    \n Filename: ".$image_type.":
    \n Type: ".$image_type_title ."
    \n reddPrimary: ".print_r($imagick_type->getImageRedPrimary(),true)."
    \n getImageBackgroundColor: ".print_r($imagick_type->getImageBackgroundColor(),true)."
    \n ColourSpace: ".print_r($imagick_type->getColorspace(),true)."
    \n\n ";

}
```

Heres an output of the script, the filenames of the image give it away

```
starting script, counting images: 

image count: 8  

 523340_10151281257702912_1277096031_n-fixed.jpg523340_10151281257702912_1277096031_n-fixed.jpg

 Filename: 6:

 Type: Truecolor

 reddPrimary: Array
(
    [x] => 0.63999998569489
    [y] => 0.33000001311302
)


 getImageBackgroundColor: ImagickPixel Object
(
)


 ColourSpace: 0


 black-and-white.jpgblack-and-white.jpg

 Filename: 6:

 Type: Truecolor

 reddPrimary: Array
(
    [x] => 0.63999998569489
    [y] => 0.33000001311302
)


 getImageBackgroundColor: ImagickPixel Object
(
)


 ColourSpace: 0


 colour-gif.gifcolour-gif.gif

 Filename: 5:

 Type: Palette Matte

 reddPrimary: Array
(
    [x] => 0.63999998569489
    [y] => 0.33000001311302
)


 getImageBackgroundColor: ImagickPixel Object
(
)


 ColourSpace: 0


 colour-image.pngcolour-image.png

 Filename: 6:

 Type: Truecolor

 reddPrimary: Array
(
    [x] => 0.63999998569489
    [y] => 0.33000001311302
)


 getImageBackgroundColor: ImagickPixel Object
(
)


 ColourSpace: 0


 yellow-should-be-black-and-white.jpgyellow-should-be-black-and-white.jpg

 Filename: 6:

 Type: Truecolor

 reddPrimary: Array
(
    [x] => 0.63999998569489
    [y] => 0.33000001311302
)


 getImageBackgroundColor: ImagickPixel Object
(
)


 ColourSpace: 0
```

Comment: compare a cloned greyscale version of the image to the original? http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/#type_greyscale not sure how that would look in php though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922654/detect-if-image-is-grayscale-or-color-using-imagick

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but looking through the docs of Imagick it looks like [there's a way to get the color of a single pixel](http://php.net/manual/en/imagickpixel.getcolor.php). Perhaps you could use something like the following:

```
$im=new Imagick( 'image.png' );
$iterator=$im->getPixelIterator();

// Tracks whether the image is black and white or not.
$b_and_w = true;

/* The tolerance value. This is how close the color of the pixel
 *must be to gray for it to count the image as black and white.
 */
$t = 5;

/* Check the value of every $x pixels. This is to allow the script
 * to run faster, but will lower the accuracy.
 */
$x = 2;

// Count of current pixel
$c = 0;

foreach( $iterator as $row => $pixels ) {
    foreach ( $pixels as $column => $pixel ){

        // If this pixel is not every $x pixel, skip it
        if(++$c % $x !== 0) continue;

        // Find unnormal color of pixel
        $color = $pixel->getColor();

        // Find average color of pixel
        $average = array_sum($color)/3;

        /* Compare the rgb values of this pixel to the average.
         * If any of them aren't close, that means it's not a shade of gray.
         */
        if(!in_array($color['r'],range(max(0,$average-$t),min(255,$average+$t)))
        || !in_array($color['g'],range(max(0,$average-$t),min(255,$average+$t)))
        || !in_array($color['b'],range(max(0,$average-$t),min(255,$average+$t)))){

            // Set our boolean to false
            $b_and_w = false;

            // Now we abandon the loops
            break 2;
        }
    }
}

if($b_and_w) echo "This image is black and white";
else         echo "This image has at least one pixel that's colored";
```

It'll compare the color of every `$x` pixels to the average color (black and white) of every pixel. If there's ever a case where they aren't close enough, the loops will exit and `$b_and_w` will be set to false. If no colored pixels are found, `$b_and_w` will remain true.

Keep in mind I have not tested this, so this may require some work on your end. Good luck.

Comment: Nice suggestions, however the colour count for the picture I posted comes up high because of the yellows.

Comment: @azz0r Unfortunately, I have to go to work, so I can't modify my script. However, yellow is blue and green, so perhaps you could try inverting the `g` and `b` values before comparing. Something like `abs(255-$color['g'])` should work for inverting the color. If this still doesn't work, try just not comparing the b and g color values, and only checking the red.

Comment: @azz0r My mistake, yellow is g and r, not g and b. Trying doing what I mentioned above, except checking only the blue value.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from iterating every pixel for checking grey  or not, you can simply find out black and white images by these steps

- Convert the colorspace of the image to HSL
- Get the mean of greenchannel
- if it is zero,then its a black and white image otherwise not

Hope this might help you

Thanks

Comment: This solution should work theoretically, but in practice, it outputs something like "0.176712" for the image in the subject. Not sure what may be the best way to threshold that value to consider image as "grayscale"