# Detect if image is grayscale or color using Imagick

Tags: php, colors, imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm attempting to try and assign a value to an image based on its 'saturation level', to see if the image is black and white or color. I'm using Imagick, and have found what seems to be the perfect code for the command line and am trying to replicate it using the PHP library.

I think I understand the concept:

1. Convert image to HSL.
2. Extract the 'g' channel (which is the S channel in HSL).
3. Calculate the mean of this channel.

#### [Command line code](http://www.multipole.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?p=81226&sid=bb7009060c35a0700322385cffa7c43a#p81226)

```
convert '$image_path' -colorspace HSL -channel g -separate +channel -format '%[fx:mean]' info:
```

#### My PHP code

```
$imagick = new Imagick($image_path);
$imagick->setColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_HSL);
print_r($imagick->getImageChannelMean(imagick::CHANNEL_GREEN));
```

#### Output

My PHP code isn't outputting the same sort of values as the command line code, though. For example, a grayscale image gives `0` for the command line code, but the PHP code gives `[mean] => 10845.392051182 [standardDeviation] => 7367.5888849872`.

Similarly, another grayscale image gives `0` vs. `[mean] => 31380.528443457 [standardDeviation] => 19703.501101904`.

A colorful image gives `0.565309` vs. `[mean] => 33991.552881892 [standardDeviation] => 16254.018540044`.

There just doesn't seem to be any kind of pattern between the different values. Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Thanks.

---

Just to add, I've also tried this PHP code

```
$imagick = new Imagick($image_path);
$imagick->setColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_HSL);
$imagick->separateImageChannel(imagick::CHANNEL_GREEN);
$imagick->setFormat('%[fx:mean]');
```

But I get an `Unable to set format` error when I try and set the format. I've also tried `setFormat('%[fx:mean] info:')`, `setFormat('%[mean]')`, `setFormat('%mean')`, etc.

---

## Update — FIXED!

Thanks to @danack for figuring out I needed to use `transformImageColorspace()` and not `setColorspace()`. The working code is below.

```
$imagick = new Imagick($image_path);
$imagick->transformImageColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_HSL);
$saturation_channel = $imagick->getImageChannelMean(imagick::CHANNEL_GREEN);
$saturation_level = $saturation_channel['mean']/65535;
```

Comment: Could you expend on what you mean by "my PHP version isn't outputting the same sort of values as the command line version"?  Are you using two separate versions of PHP?

Comment: Sorry — I think it's bad wording on my part! I'll edit that. It's the same version of PHP, I just mean the two versions of code, i.e. the command line code vs. the PHP code.

Comment: @danack
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsku5.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setFormat doesn't replicate the command line option `-format` - the one in Imagick tries to set the image format, which should be png, jpg etc. The one in the command line is setting the format for `info` - the closest match for which in Imagick is calling `$imagick->identifyImage(true)` and parsing the results of that.

Also you're just calling the wrong function - it should be transformImageColorspace not setColorSpace. If you use that you can use the statistics from getImageChannelMean.

There are other ways to test for greyness which may be more appropriate under certain circumstances. The first is to convert the a clone of the image to grayscale, and then compare it to the original image:

```
$imagick = new Imagick($image_path);
$imagickGrey = clone $imagick;
$imagickGrey->setimagetype(\Imagick::IMGTYPE_GRAYSCALE);

$differenceInfo = $imagick->compareimages($imagickGrey, \Imagick::METRIC_MEANABSOLUTEERROR);

if ($differenceInfo['mean'] <= 0.0000001) {
    echo "Grey enough";
}
```

That would probably be appropriate if you image had areas of color that were also transparent - so they theoretically have color, but not visibly.

Or if you only care about whether the image is of a grayscale format:

```
$imageType = $imagick->getImageType();
if ($imageType === \Imagick::IMGTYPE_GRAYSCALE || 
    $imageType === Imagick::IMGTYPE_GRAYSCALEMATTE) {
     //This is grayscale
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution as a way of detecting if the image is grayscale, but I'm just wondering if you have any idea why `$imagick->setColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_HSL);` isn't working? Ideally (which is slightly different to my original question), I'd like a value between 0.0 and 1.0 based on the average saturation of the image. I boosted the saturation to maximum on an image in Photoshop and the command line script gave 0.995 (close enough to 1.0), but the above script gave 0.22 — what does the 0.22 represent? It seems to be about the largest number being outputted so far.

Comment: Just to clarify, rather than simply classifying an image as grayscale or not, I'd ideally like to be able to choose an image based on **how colorful** it is. Your code does this, although the results are slightly different to calculating the average saturation. If it isn't possible, I can divide the output value from your code by 0.25ish to get a value normalised to 1.0, but I'm curious. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: "just wondering if you have any idea why $imagick->setColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_HSL); isn't working? " Looks like it's buggered. That's the technical term. setColorSpace seems to be having zero effect on the image - I'll try to dig into it further as I should know what it does.

Comment: "I'd ideally like to be able to choose an image based on how colorful it is." That's a different question. You can probably do it now without using the broken setColorspace function by i) splitting it into rgb channels, ii) Calling compareimages between r+g and g+b with METRIC_MEANSQUAREERROR as the summing term.

Comment: Thanks, @danack! If you do manage to figure out what's going on with `setColorspace`, it'd be good to know. You've been a great help, though!

Comment: @Davey Simple errors are always the best .... transformImageColorspace not setImageColorSpace

Comment: @Danack, sir, i have tried your code, but it shows "Undefined index: mean" where when i check the return array it has only numeric array like this: "Array
(
    [0] => Imagick Object
        (
        )

    [1] => 0
)", so, should i sue "1"? thanks in advance

Comment: @Zakir_SZH ask a separate question, and include the Imagick version.

Comment: @Danack, thanks for your response sir, please have a look at the below question, you help is highly appreciated :)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415910/imagick-color-detection-is-not-accurate

Answer (score 1):

If your images have tint. (from scanner as example) you should do auto color for them before detecting gray scale.
You should `normalizeImage(imagick::CHANNEL_ALL)` for all separate channels of image. `separateImageChannel()`

But

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a command line [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=19580#p81226):

```
convert image.png -colorspace HSL -channel g -separate +channel -format "%[fx:mean]" info:
```

It prints a number between 0 and 1, where zero means grayscale.

Comment: Thanks, this works very good!

++ convert ../image_bw.jpg -colorspace HSL -channel g -separate +channel -format '%[fx:mean]' info:
+ VALUE_RAW=0.0348832

++ convert ../image_col.jpg -colorspace HSL -channel g -separate +channel -format '%[fx:mean]' info:
+ VALUE_RAW=0.435082

I'm using now that if the value is < 0.1, the image is grayscale. If it's 0.1-1, it's color.